# Vector dot product vs. magnitude times cosine for distance to plane

Tags: geometry, point, projection, plane

Let us have 3 points, `p0`, `p1`, `p2` in 3d space.

These 3 points form a plane.

I have already computed and normalized the normal of the plane (`n`).

Now, given a point exterior to my plane (`p`) I would like the distance from this point to my plane.

I have found this question [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55189333/how-to-get-distance-from-point-to-plane-in-3d) that treats the solution however I am confused about the final dot product.

In this figure:

[image: fig. 1]

The distance from `p` to the plane is given as `|dot ( p-p0 , n )|` so the dot between `n` and the vector going from `p0` to `p` (lets name this vector `P` (capital P)).

From what I can see using the figure and my own logic, is that the distance from `p` to the place is basically the length of the projection of `P` onto `n`. But the length of this projection is not a complete dot product. A complete dot product would be `|P||n|cos(P,n)`. But I have found that the length of the projection of `P` onto `n` is just `|P|cos(P,n)`.

So my questions are:

1. Is my thinking correct that the distance from `p` to the plane is the projection of `P` onto `n`? If not why?
2. which interpretation is correct and why?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a math problem, not programming, and best for https://math.stackexchange.com/ Also, do not ask multiple questions in one posting. [ask]

Comment: @Rob I assume you already voted to close the question I linked, correct? Because they treat the exact same subject.

Answer (score 1):

Distance is length of perpendicular projection of `P` onto the plane `P0P1P2` (or another interpretation with the same result - projection of `P0P` vector onto `n` direction)

Perhaps you forgot that your normal `n` is normalized vector, so it has unit length, and

```
|P||n|cos(P,n) == |P|cos(P,n)
```

Comment: Ooh so basically both my interpretation and the one in the linked question are correct because `|n|` is a neutral term and doesn't affect anything. Correct? Also, if `|n|` was not normalized, then would my interpretation be correct?

Comment: if `n` is not normalized, correct formula is `|dot ( p-p0 , n )| / |n|`. What your interpretation do you mean? `length of the projection of P onto n` is not correct

Comment: Perhaps we consider different meanings of `projection of P onto n`